# iOS 7 autolayout engine set different constraints than iOS 8

Tags: ios

I have a UIView, and I set the constraint via xib like below:
height = 64;
align trailing to super view : 0
align leading to super view : 0
align top space to super view : 0

on iOS 7 iPhone 5S simulator, at run time, I see the constraints like this:

width = height * 6.25

and the hight becomes 51, while width is 320

However, on iOS 8, it is like this:

height = 64

And by autolayout calculation, the width is 320.

Seems like iOS 8 auto layout engine is giving the right output, but on iOS 7 iPhone 5S simulator, it is wrong.

If I use iPhone 4S or 5 simulator for iOS 7, issue is gone. I have no real iPhone 5S on iOS 7. I am wondering is it possible to be iPhone 5S bug?

How can I fix it?

EDIT:
This is the constraints even before [super viewDidLoad]:

```
(lldb) po [self.ChartNavigationView constraints]
<__NSArrayM 0x7fa20bb77650>(
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ec10 UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0.width == 6.25*UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0.height>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ec60 UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0.centerX == UILabel:0x7fa20be2d780.centerX>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ecb0 V:|-(30)-[UILabel:0x7fa20be2d780]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ed00 V:|-(25)-[UIButton:0x7fa20be26d60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ed50 H:|-(10)-[UIButton:0x7fa20be26d60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2eda0 H:[UIButton:0x7fa20be28a00]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2edf0 H:[UIButton:0x7fa20be28ed0]-(8)-[UIButton:0x7fa20be28a00]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ee40 V:|-(25)-[UIButton:0x7fa20be28a00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa20be2ee90 V:|-(25)-[UIButton:0x7fa20be28ed0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa20be2d6a0 )>
)
```

Comment: no, and it only happens on 5s simulator. What I can guess is the width is 320 in both case, so it recauclate height to 51, rather than 64 as I set. seems autolayout engine is producing this conatraints

Comment: I am using size class, but only use portrait mode

Comment: I disabled size classes, and issues still there. One interesting thing is that only iPhone 5S+iOS 7 simulator can have width=6.25*height. Any other combination is fine.

Comment: hold on, let me try ceate a demo project if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Hello matt, I cannot reproduce it in demo project and I cannot upload origin project too. I read your book and I know some the auto layout stuff. After I debug, I found even before [super viewDidLoad], the auto layout engine has got `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb95ae51a90 UIView:0x7fb95ae50520.width == 6.25*UIView:0x7fb95ae50520.height>`, but I never set it this way

Comment: yes, but I just setup the constraints via xib... That's why I am confused, after I cannot see this weird thing on other iphone simulator.

Comment: I can, but I don't think this can help, because I cannot reproduce it...

Comment: if you could come to Beijing or I can come to visit you, I definitely can show you. I will find what I can to debug it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is xml text file. I searched, but no 6.25 found.

Comment: is it possible we can have some remote connection, so I can share my screen?

Comment: this is my xib:https://github.com/liuxuan30/ALDemo